# Induction proof involving Euler Totient Function

Tags: number-theory

Let $\varphi$ be the Euler totient function

Qi) show that if $r$ is a power of a prime number then $\sum_{d|r} \varphi(d) = r.$

Qii) Show that if $n \geq 2$ then there is a decomposition of n as a product of positive integers:$$n = rs,$$ where $r$ is a power of a prine; $s<n$ and $ hcf (r,s) = 1$

Qiii) Hence prove by induction that for all positive integers $n$, $$\sum_{d|n} \varphi(d) = n$$

I've managed to complete part i) and ii) and I'm now stuck on part iii)

I've attempted the induction by the standard way: I've shown it holds for $n = 1, 2$ and have assumed it holds for $n = k$ - for the $k+1$ case we know that  by part ii) $\exists r,s$ s.t. $k+1 = rs$ where $r$ is product of primes and $k+1 >s$ and $r,s$ are coprime - however I'm not sure if this is leading somewhere and I really don't see how I can progress. If anyone could show me the way it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Assume the property holds for **all** values less than $k$, then show that $k$ also holds.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to induct on the number of prime factors of n. Since $\phi(1) = 1$, the result holds when $n = 1$. If $n$ is prime, then $\sum_{d|n} \phi(d) = \phi(1) + \phi(n) = 1 + (n - 1) = n$. For the inductive step, suppose that $n$ has more than one prime factor and the result holds for all positive integers whose number of prime factors is less than the number of prime factors of $n$.. Write $n = p^lm$, where $p$ is a prime not dividing $m$. The positive divisors of $n$ are of the form $p^k u$ where $0 \le k \le l$ and $u | m$. Now $\phi(p^ku) = \phi(p^k)\phi(u) = (p^k - p^{k-1})\phi(u)$ for all $0 \le k \le l$ and $u|m$. Hence

\begin{align}\sum_{d|n} \phi(d) &= \sum_{u|m} \phi(u) + \sum_{u|m} \phi(pu) + \cdots + \sum_{u|m} \phi(p^lu)\\
&= (1 + (p - 1) + (p^2 - p) + \cdots + (p^l - p^{l-1}))\sum_{u|m} \phi(u)\\
&= p^lm \quad (\text{by the induction hypothesis})\\
&= n
\end{align}